# TS array map needs type assertion - why?

Tags: typescript

This code

```js
function myFilter(debts:Map<string, number>) : Map<string, number>{
  return new Map([...debts]
    .map(d => [d[0], Math.round(d[1] * 10) / 10]) // error
    .filter(d => d[1] != 0)
  )
}
```

gives an error because the `map()` ostensibly can yield `[string | number][][]`.

But this does work:

```js
function myFilter(debts:Map<string, number>) : Map<string, number>{
  return new Map([...debts]
    .map(d => [d[0], Math.round(d[1] * 10) / 10] as [string, number])
    .filter(d => d[1] != 0)
  )
}
```

I don't understand why this assertion is necessary.

Comment: `.map(d => [ ... ] as const)` or `.map<[string, number]>(...)` should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why?

Because TypeScript does not infer a tuple return type in your callback:

```ts
.map(d => [d[0], Math.round(d[1] * 10) / 10])
```

It is inferred to be a union of all of the possible value types at each element: If you rewrite it using an explicit return statement, you can see the inferred type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DEYBsoFMBOAFACa4BGUAzgFwCyAhgA4A8lU+MYA5gDSJghkZAgD4AlImqIGLNh258BQ0QG8AUIkT5cUEPiRhcAd2lNCAbQB010hUoBdDZsSXkZ4ogC8IxOufOIBDYtXEoQHC9Ec2JzAAZ7PgYoAAtLfDhwYhJzAEZ7RAAqRBzYiQB6YviAbid-fzKygD0AflrnbV19ELCcGv8AXzE2y2BsPCIPb0QYvMQAQk9EUqch-rUgA)

```ts
.map(d => {
  const result = [d[0], Math.round(d[1] * 10) / 10];
      //^? const result: (string | number)[]
  return result;
})
```

---

Alternate solution:

You can also supply a generic type parameter when using [`Array.prototype.map<T>()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=3&ssc=5&pln=3&pc=68#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DEYBsoFMBOAFACa4BGUAzgFwCyAhgA4A8lU+MYA5gDSJghkZAgD4AlImqIGLNh258BQ0QG8AUIkT5cUEPiRhcAd2lNCAbQB010hUoBdDZsSXkTZubmde-QcPz2IiSIALwiiObE5gAM9nwMUAAWlvhw4MQk5gCM9ogAVIhZ0RIA9IWxYk6alsDYeETEoeFROYgAhCGIxU6VAL5qQA)

```ts
.map<[string, number]>(d => [d[0], Math.round(d[1] * 10) / 10])
```

This will satisfy the compiler and help ensure that the value returned by your callback is assignable to the supplied generic type.

Comment: Thanks! I wondered why Typescript couldn’t infer that `d[0]` has to be a string and `d[1]` a number from the type of `d`.